# Rails: how to display a list of items from one model filtered by an attribute located on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

In RailsLet' say I have 3 Models A, B, and C each with their own controllers.

Model A

has_many :b

Model B has attributes :a_id and :c_id (the foreign keys to B and A)

belongs_to :a
belongs_to :c

Model C with attributes :item1, :item2, etc.

has_many :b

I'd like to display a list of items from Model C filtered by a specific a_id.  For various reasons I prefer not to carry the b_id foreign key on Model C. What's the best way to achieve this? I thought of arrays, but seems to complex. I'm sure there is an easier way.

Thanks

Comment: item1, :item2, etc. are columns in database table for model C ??

Comment: B points to itself or is this a typo?

Comment: yeah that was a typo, corrected now.

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 0):

try giving relationship this way

```
Model A
  has_and_belongs_to_many :c

Model C
  has_and_belongs_to_many :a

Model B
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :c
```

so that you get data like this way try in your console

```
# a = user, c = customer
@user.customers # you get all customers for particular user
@customer.users # you get all users for particular customer
```

see more in [HATBM](http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/rails-has_and_belongs_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
C.find(:all, :joins => [:B], :conditions => ["a_id = ", id_of_a])
```

Comment: some further explanation might assist the OP

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't want to not mess about with model associations because of other dependencies I have, so I came up with a solution involving pluck.

I used something like this:

```
@pluckfromModelC = ModelB.where("attribute_I_want_mapping =?", @attribute_to_map_from).uniq.pluck(:item_id)
```

Which produced an array.

In my view I then created a loop

```
<% @pluckfromModelC.each do |x| %>

    <% @founditem = Item.find(x) %>
    <%= @founditem.description %>
     ...etc.

<% end %>
```